# SQL Server : does an CTE update work like a transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use a query like this to update some columns of a table:

```
WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.dtDate ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        important.Table T
    WHERE 
        bWorking = 1
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET iIDfkToOtherTable = 6
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

There are two queries in this statement (`SELECT` and `UPDATE`), so I'm not sure if another user will be able to change the "important.Table" values while I am between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`. Can someone give me a clue? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and exepct result?

Comment: There is only one query here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is essentially a single query for the sake of atomicity.  It would be essentially the same as UPDATE ... FROM in those terms:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/84206

In fact here's a similar but different question that suggests such a CTE for accomplishing atomicity in lieu of a two step select/update:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42470136/84206

Comment: Thanks. I'm dealing with this because I use two bots saving and retrieving data in the same table and they are always deathlocking. I'll keep cheking it.

Comment: @DavidSantiagoBermdezCaldern I don't want to get into extended offtopic discussion, but usually if you had deadlocking due to a "select then update" type of problem, what you see is two queries with a shared lock trying to be escalate to an exclusive lock for the update.  This article is old but a good starting point, there's still reports and different ways to view transaction lock types(exclusive/shared): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/224453

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as two queries. That's procedural thinking. SQL Server is set based, and in this case you are defining an end state "This set of data will have this transformation applied".

As a single definition it will always be atomic.